# RubyMotion and Dropbox

Tags: ios, dropbox, rubymotion

I'm working on getting the Dropbox Sync SDK working in my RubyMotion app. I've looked around and only found one other guy looking for [help](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubymotion/YbwSYmGEbMU), however he's using the Dropbox Core SDK and I wasn't able to fix it the way he was able to.  Here's what I've done so far:

1. Downloaded the Dropbox Sync SDK, moved it to vendor/Dropbox.framework
2. Added `app.vendor_project 'vendor/Dropbox.framework', :static, :products => ['Dropbox'], :headers_dir => 'Headers'` and `app.frameworks += ['Security','QuartzCore']` to my Rakefile.
3. Ran `rake clean`, then `rake` and got the following output.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator >::compare(char const*) const", referenced from:
>   fetch_metadata(dbx_client*, HttpRequester&, dbx_path_val const&, bool, bool, bool) in Dropbox(sync.o)
>
> ...

I can give the full stack trace if needed. Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks a boat load for any help.

Edit: Stack trace using markrickert's method:

```
:~/Development/simple|master⚡ ⇒  rake
rake aborted!
[!] Unable to find a specification for `Dropbox-Sync-API-SDK`.
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/cocoapods-0.23.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:195:in `find_cached_set'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/cocoapods-0.23.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in find_dependency_specs'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/cocoapods-0.23.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:113:in `message'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/cocoapods-0.23.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:152:in `block in find_dependency_specs'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/cocoapods-0.23.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:148:in `each'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/cocoapods-0.23.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:148:in `find_dependency_specs'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/cocoapods-0.23.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in resolve'
...
```

^^ Needed to run `pod setup` to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Dropbox Sync Podspec file](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Dropbox-Sync-API-SDK/2.0.0-b5/Dropbox-Sync-API-SDK.podspec) to get an idea of what you need to do in order to correctly include it in your file... or you can just use the Cocoapod:

In your Gemfile:

```
gem "motion-cocoapods", '~> 1.3.0'
gem "cocoapods"
```

And in your rakefile:

```
Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  # Use `rake config' to see complete project settings.
  app.name = 'Whatever'

  app.pods do
    pod 'Dropbox-Sync-API-SDK'
  end
end
```

Then when you run `rake pod:install` it should automatically include all the dependencies and compile and allow you to use the SDK.

Comment: Thanks bunches for replying, I've added a stack trace above showing the error I get following these steps.

Comment: Just kidding, I got it. I needed to run `pod setup`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for accepting my answer. Good on you for putting the `pod setup` in your original question... you only have to do that once per machine to get cocoapods ready to go.